# How to know what kind of malware infected the PC?

Tags: windows-7, security, virus, anti-virus, malware

I downloaded a software from cnet, and cnet downloader installed malicious software. I removed them using the add  or remove program but the malware are still there, some toolbar, and some backup software, although i did not approve to download these software.

I have 2 antivirus, avg internet security 2013 which is kinda useless, and there's malwarebyte pro which detected 15 virus on my windows 7 using the quick scan.

Before i scanned my pc, i tried to use gtalk and google said that my account was blocked because someone tried to login, it was my ip and i know it could be just a mistake. But now i know that i have at the very least 15 malware on pc.

So I want to know is there's a way to know what kind of malware do i have? And from where it was downloaded?

- I want to know if CNET did all that, if so i want to contact them about it.
- I want to know if i have a keylogger or not, I changed gmail password but don't to sign in yet, not until i make sure that my pc is totally clean, if i have keylogger or RAT, then I'm screwed, the second i log in, the password is gonna be sent to the hacker.

I know some might call me paranoid, but i believe that it's my right to know what kind of malware infected my pc and where did it come from, and not just remove them and move on. So is there some kind of database where i can export my malwarebyte report, where they analyze what i have and what ip sent it? Is it possible to trace malware?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to definitely tell what the source was, but most antivirus applications will list the malware's definition name. That name can be looked up in a few different [encyclopedias](http://www.bitdefender.com/resourcecenter/virus-encyclopedia/) to determine what the type and behavior of the virus may be. Some even include the estimated release date and country of origin.

Comment: Probably CNET didn't infect your computer, although you might have installed adware (software that gets additionally installed, by choice, on their installers). On a side note, you shouldn't run two antivirus suites on the same PC.

Comment: . . . 2 Activly scanning antivirus programs, using more than one antivirus to do a manuel scanning is not a problem. MWB can activly scan and has huristics in the pro version of it. Hurustics can be more sensitive to all odd programs.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Well if my PC got infected because of CNET downloader in any possible way, I want to contact them, that does not make them any less guilty, distributing bad software to people, and how do you expect me to trust one antivirus? I trusted Avg internet security which is a very hight rated antivirus for many years, and it sucks bad

Comment: @moses thank you, I'll take a look at it, i was hoping for an automated way though, import the report, the database analyzes it and gives results

Comment: @Fischer (and trying to avoid an extended discussion) As I said on a question about security, CNET's main goal is to earn money - as such they aren't going to do that if their site gains a reputation for having malware. They gain money mostly through running ads on their site (and by placing them inside other applications). You can contact them "easily" through their support center. As Psycogeek stated (and you can search SU for this) it's a **Bad Idea** to run two antivirus suites on one PC, the main reason is because they don't know about each other. Just choose the one you trust more.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard **it's a Bad Idea to run two antivirus suites on one PC, the main reason is because they don't know about each other. Just choose the one you trust more** I dont know abt that, i dont trust any, u see malwarebyte detected 15 viruses, then i ran avg and it detected 7 more, i guess im gonna keep both, coz i dont trust any, i guess im gonna open another question to discuss that subject

Comment: @Fischer Don't open another question when there are thousands more that answer this question.

Comment: CNET installers often contain junk or try to add very bad apps. I never use such installers. There are others like that too, not only them.